# growing permsize when loading lots of data into memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I always thought, that the memory of permsize of a JVM is filled with loading classes during starting up the JVM. Probably also with stuff like JNI during runtime ? But in general it should not growth during runtime "signifcantly".

Now I noticed, that since I load a lots of data (20GB) into the heapspace, which max is 32GB ( ArrayLists of Data ), then I get a 'OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space'.

Is there any correlation or just accidentally ?

I know howto increase the permsize. This is not the question.

Comment: Is it a webapp with hot deployed JSPs? When a servlet container like Tomcat compiles JSPs, that's a completely new class into PermGen, but the old JSP class isn't necessarily removed.

Comment: @Stewart . Thanks a lot. This is a good explanation and good to know. But my Servlet has no JSP's its only a servlet.

Comment: I suggest trying a JVM memory profiler. It may tell you what the classes are in PermGen, as it grows.

Answer (score 1):

With tomcat, I have set the following for increasing PermGen space.

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

You may like to do something like above.
I have set in MB(256m), I am not sure how to set for GB.

Hope helps.

Comment: I know how to set the permsize. This was not the question. I would like to understand why the permsize growth during runtime and if there is any correlation to the effect I discribed.

Answer (score 1):

The **PermGen** memory space is not part of the heap (sometimes this causes confusion). It's where some kind of objects are allocated, like
**Class** objects, **Method** objects, and the **pool of strings** objects. Unlike the name would indicate, this memory space is also collected (during 
the FullGC), but often bring major headaches, as known 
**OutOfMemoryError**.

Problems with bursting PermGen are difficult to diagnose precisely
because it is not the application objects . Most of the cases, the problem is connected to
an exaggerated amount of classes that are loaded into memory. A well known issue, was the use
of Eclipse with many plugins ( WTP ) with default JVM settings . Many classes were loaded in memory and ends with a burst of the permGEN.

Another problem of PermGen are the ***hot deploys*** in application servers. For several reasons, the server cannot release
the context classes at the destroy time . A new version of the application is then loaded,
**but old the classes remains, increasing the PermGen.**

*That's why sometimes we need to restart the whole container because of the **PermGen**.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. So doesn't ( or should ) reaching the limit of maxpermsize trigger a full GC.

Comment: I think it should trigger. But maybe, for some reason, even the gc could not be able to shrink the permGem. A profile tool like jvisualvm can show what is happening inside the permGem.